# Multiple Issues connecting pi to new network (ssh)

Tags: networking, wifi, headless, wpa-supplicant

I have a rpi 4b that up until this point has worked fine on my old wifi network. I've had to switch ISP from Telstra to Optus and am on a new network (old network yet to be shut off). I only access it through ssh (though I do have VNC viewer and can use a GUI).

I tried connecting my pi to the modem with an ethernet cable, but it doesn't appear at all on the network when I go to my gateway. I've connected to my pi on the old network, gone into `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and have:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=AU

network={
    ssid="new_network"
    psk="new-pwd"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
network={
    ssid="old_network"
    psk="old_pwd"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

I've tried turning the old network off before booting it, but when it boots it will never connect to the new network. I do not want to try removing the old network from the wpa_supplicant.conf file as I will then have 0 means of accessing my pi again. I have even tried going into the GUI to check the network, and despite having connected to the pi through wifi, the GUI still says 0 wireless interfaces found.

I also tried `sudo raspi-config` and setting the network through that menu to no avail.

I have a limited amount of time until the old network is cancelled so I am rather pressed for time.

I'm completely lost as to what to do now.

EDIT: I have located a micro hdmi : hdmi adapter that I did not believe I had. I am now able to access the pi without network access if there are any potential solutions that require it.

Comment: What is the wireless region / country set to on your new network? Are the old and new networks 2.4Ghz 5Ghz or both?

Comment: My new network is AU as well. Old was 2.4GHz. I have both 2.4GHz and 5GHz new networks. I have tried both in the wpa_supplicant.conf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have inadvertently solved my own problem and I am very ashamed to say I don't know exactly what did it. I did a number of things at the same time and my pi now boots and connects to the new network just fine. Sincerest apologies for not being able to pinpoint the issue.

- In `/etc/network/interfaces`, I changed `iface wlan0 inet dhcp` to `iface wlan0 inet manual`.
- I went into sudo raspi-config and re-entered an SSID and passphrase through the network-options menu (for the ~4th time)
- Given my newfound ability to control my rpi without an ssh connection, I removed the old network from `wpa_supplicant.conf` and left only the 5GHz network in there (along with another network that is my university's).
- I then rebooted the rpi.

Interestingly enough, I am still unable to see the raspberry pi show up on my network gateway, though I can locate it with an IP scanning program and SSH into it with my laptop.

Comment: If you did anything in interfaces you broke dhcpcd networking. Delete whatever you added and connect from the networking icon on the desktop.

Comment: Networks have never shown up under that icon on my pi, even when I had default settings and first set up the device. I've had to do everything in wpa_supplicant from the first time I launched it.